# Can I get a visa for Germany or The Netherlands if I have a South African refugee travel document?

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, refugees

I'm from Somalia and living in South Africa; I have a refugee travel document issued by South Africa. Can I get a Schengen visa to travel to Germany or The Netherlands with it? Do the German/Netherlands consulates issue visas to such a document holder?

Answer (score 4):

Refugee travel documents issued by South Africa are (according to [lists maintained by the European Commission](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/prado-recognised-documents.html)) recognized by most Schengen countries except Estonia, Latvia, Malta and Poland. So you should be okay for Germany and the Netherlands.

Remember that you still need to apply for a visa in your travel document.